# Share a Modal window via E-Mail

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I would like share a modal window via E-Mail.

What I would like to accomplish is that on click on the "Share" button users can send an email with the link of that Modal and when you click on that link the website loads with that Modal already open.

I created a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/pcx98bvs/:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    ...
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <a href="mailto:test@gmail.com"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Share</button></a>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Any tips?

Thanks a lot in advance
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `body` query string parameter to your `href` that links to the modal
Example: `<a href="mailto:test@gmail.com?body=https://yourwebsite#modal">`
Then put this script on your page so you can trigger the modal by making use of the passed hash from the url

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var target = document.location.hash;
    $(target).modal('show');
});
```

Comment: I tried and still not working :/

my domain is something like subdomain.maindomain.com/en/

Comment: @Fulew what happened?

Comment: The page simply reload normally and the modal does not open. I just see the overlay bgcolor of the modal but the modal does not appears.

What i tried is `subdomain.maindomain.com/en/#myModal` and also `subdomain.maindomain.com#myModal` without results

Comment: @Fulew i could probably provide you a jquery solution

Comment: this would be great

Comment: @Fulew yes, test it. just need browser to be js-enabled. please accept my post as answer so you can help me out with my reputation